# Google News: How long do the full or realtime coverage webpages last?

Tags: google-news

Sample URL (realtime coverage): http://news.google.com/news/rtc?pz=1&cf=all&ncl=dR01miRCSxKz1eMZO-MiyyqYSalaM&topic=m

Full coverage URL of the same topic: http://news.google.com/news/story?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=m&ncl=dR01miRCSxKz1eMZO-MiyyqYSalaM

How long do these realtime or full coverage pages last? Will the links to them or the pages expire after a certain amount of time has passed?

Answer (score 2):

It is still possible to look back at "Full Coverage" of news articles back in 2008 ([random example](http://news.google.com/news/story?q=2009%20election&ncl=aiJf0uNwVye9p1M&sa=X) via "all X articles" links), so those pages remain. The link appears to be the same as well, so that should work into the future.

The real time coverage option is new, so it is hard to talk about the longevity of those pages. The [Google support page](http://support.google.com/news/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2602970&topic=2428791&ctx=topic) doesn't mention how long they will last. There isn't a compelling reason that they would age off, particularly given the work being done to tie it into Google+.